# Laravel редирект с данными формы

Tags: laravel

Учу лару, такое задание - " Спросите у пользователя email с помощью формы. Если этот email корректный, то выполните редирект на другое действие и выведите в представлении этого действия переданный email и сообщение о том, что он корректен."

роут

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/test', 'TestController@form');
Route::get('/test/result', 'TestController@result');
```

контроллер

```
    <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function form(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            if(preg_match('~@~m', $request->input('email'), $match)){
                return redirect('/test/result')->withInput();
            }
           else{
               return view('test.form', ['error'=>'email не корректный!']);
           }
        }
        if($request->isMethod('get')){
            return view('test.form');
        }
    }
public function result(Request $request)
{
    return view('test.result', ['request'=> $request]);
}
}
```

представление по адресу /test/result

```
{{ $request->input('email') }}
```

представление по адресу /test  (форма с которой мыло отправляю)

```
    @if (!empty($error))
    {{$error}}
    @endif
<form action="" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

В итоге редирект на белую страницу, ни ошибок ни данных.
В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

В форме с которой отправляете запрос скорее всего не отправляется сам запрос,так как action у вас не указан.
Во первых задайте name роуту

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/test', 'TestController@form')->name('test');
Route::get('/test/result', 'TestController@result')->name('result');
```

В форме задайте вот так

```
    @if (!empty($error))
    {{$error}}
    @endif
<form action="{{route('test')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

В контроллере же,в функции form укажите вместо redirect -> view() и в нём страницу на которую хотите перебросить пользователя.

```
public function form(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            if(preg_match('~@~m', $request->input('email'), $match)){
                return view('test.result', ['request'=> $request->input('email')]);
            }
           else{
               return view('test.form', ['error'=>'email не корректный!']);
           }
        }
        if($request->isMethod('get')){
            return view('test.form');
        }
```

Если возникнут ошибки,напишите их в комментарии - пообсуждаем

Comment: return view('test.result', ['request'=> $request->input('email')]) можно заменить на return route('result') но потребуется корректировка в контроллере. Если понадобится именно route - напишите я исправлю код.

Comment: Спасибо за готовность помочь. Решить задачку другим способом я бы тоже смог, но я хотел бы понять как работает редирект и ->withInput().  Пока я не понимаю как передать в редиректе данные формы именно через ->withInput()

Comment: Подскажите вашу версию laravel,посмотрю  в документации.

Comment: В новейших версиях laravel используется return redirect()->route('result',[и данные тут]);

Comment: Большое спасибо, реально задачка из лары версии 5, теперь понятно почему не получалось! Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Изменил в контроллере на return  redirect()->route('result',['email'=> $request->input('email')]);  так же добавил имя роутеру и в форме прописал вывод {{ $email }}   в итоге редирект идет, но ошибка $email is undefined

Comment: Укажите в аргументах функции public function result(email)
{
    return view('test.result', ['email'=> $email]);
}

Comment: Поэтому и не получается

Comment: Получилось, спасибо! Последний вопрос, если позволите - почему редирект идет методом GET ? ведь return  redirect()->route('result',['email'=> $request->input('email')]);  ссылается на роут, а роут у я пробовал делать Route::post('/test/result', 'TestController@result')->name('result');  получаю ошибку, работает только если роут get